# sql date + time + time diff calculation

Tags: sql, datetime

say I had three columns, depart_date, depart_time, and depart_diff(mean the real depart_time - planned time, unit in minutes), how can I get the really time using sql.

For example, I had depart date :2017-05-05;
                   depart time :00:20:00;
                   depart_diff: -30 (meaning 30 mins earlier)

I should get real depart_date:2017-05-04;
             real depart_time:23:50:00

Thanks

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about [DATEADD()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql)

In your case should this should be:

```
declare @depart_date as date = '2017-05-05'
declare @depart_time as time = '00:20:00'
declare @depart_diff as int = -30


SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE ,@depart_diff, CAST(@depart_date AS DATETIME)+CAST(@depart_time AS DATETIME))
```

The third argument is `@depart_date` and `@depart_time` concatenated as `datetime`.

Comment: If I need process a lot of data, say three column and thousands of row, Is this working?

Comment: @HengZhao yeah it's working, why not? try it and tell me if something it's not right